# Why does std::bind() tries to copy my object?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm using VS2010.
In the constructor of my non-compyable Scene class I have :

```
auto& character_mgr = CharacterManager::Instance();
    character_mgr.initialize();
character_mgr.add_observer(  std::bind( &Scene::on_character_event, *this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2 ) );
```

Here add_observer is defined as :

```
void add_observer( Observer observer ){ ... }
```

with Observer defined as :

```
typedef std::function< void ( CharacterEvent, const Character& ) > Observer;
```

The problem is that the compiler tells me there is an attempt to copy my Scene, that I provided in the bind using `*this`, thinking it would keep a reference on it, not trying to copy it when I copy the functor generated by the binding.

1. Why does it try to copy my object? Is it normal?
2. How should I do to avoid the copy while providing the member function of my object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. It's the default behaviour.
2. To pass by reference, try using std::ref .

Comment: Thanks, most complete answer so validated, the other answer are good too. I understand the problem now.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid copying, pass `this` instead of `*this`, or as the other answer, `std::ref(*this)`.

```
character_mgr.add_observer(  std::bind( &Scene::on_character_event, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2 ) );
```

Take a look at U[sing bind with pointers to members](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/bind/bind.html#with_member_pointers).